# Count the number of clicks on the buttons error and insert in the database PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have 3 buttons each button means a type of error.

I want to add all my clicks into a database

```
 <button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 1</button>
 <button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 2</button>
 <button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 3</button>

 Table : 

    Code |Button1|Button2|Button3
```

//Click & De-click :

```
  $(function()
   {

    jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(d,c){
        function cb(){ [d,c][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
        return this.on("click", cb);
   };

    var all_errors = {'E1':0,'E2':0,'E3':0};

    var btn1 = false;
    btn2 = false;
    btn3 = false;

    $("[id^='E1_']").clickToggle(function(){
        all_errors.E1++;
        console.log(errors);
    },function(){
        if(all_errors .E1 > 0) all_errors .E1--;
    });


});
```

I need help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: php is run on the server while javascript is run on the client. You'd have to listen fro a click event and send an ajax call to the server.

Comment: I modify my code but i still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function clickCal(value){

  var clicks = parseInt($('#div_'+value).html())+1;
  $('#div_'+value).html(clicks);
  //Call ajax method to save into server
  $.ajax({ url: 'action.php',
     data: {identifier: value,value: clicks},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
         console.log(output);
     }
  });
}
</script>
```

Html code

```
 <button id="E1_<?= $count; ?>" onclick="clickCal(1)">error type 1</button>
 <button id="E2_<?= $count; ?>" onclick="clickCal(2)">error type 2</button>
 <button id="E3_<?= $count; ?>" onclick="clickCal(3)">error type 3</button>
 <br/>
 <span>Click of button 1: </span> <div id="div_1">0</div>
 <br/>
 <span>Click of button 2: </span> <div id="div_2">0</div>
 <br/>
 <span>Click of button 3: </span> <div id="div_3">0</div>
 <br/>
```

//PHP code, Actions.php will have following code to save into database

```
$identifier = $_POST['identifier'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
//You can INSERT OR UPDATE as per your need.
```

Please let me know if you've any queries.

Comment: This is incomplete.. Mentions nothing about saving to the DB.. Which is the missing component..

Comment: " {identifier: value,value: clicks"  whati's the identifier and value?

Comment: Identifier is the whom you click, a button number and value is number of clicks of that button.